# Basis in which $T$ has Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I am studying Jordan normal form and still trying to piece it together. Got stuck on this question.

Given a matrix representation of $T: V \rightarrow  V$ in basis $A = (v_1,..,v_n)$ by
\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & \lambda & 0 & \dots  & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \lambda & \dots  & 0 & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & \lambda & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 1 & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}

In which basis $B$ has $M_{B}(T)$ Jordan normal form?

$M_{A}(T)$ has ones below the diagonal instead, so I am guessing there's an easy way to figure $B$ out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $B = (v_n,v_{n-1},\dots,v_1)$

Comment: In general, reversing the order of your basis "flips the matrix upside down"